# Filter data in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I have some column data in TensorFlow and I'd like to filter on one of the columns, like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tfv1
tfv1.enable_v2_behavior()

csv_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('heart.csv', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/applied-dl/heart.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
target = df.pop('target')
df['thal'] = pd.Categorical(df['thal'])
df['thal'] = df.thal.cat.codes

# Use interleave() and prefetch() to read many files concurrently.
#files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern=input_file_pattern, shuffle=True, seed=123456789)
#dataset = files.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.RecordIODataset(x).prefetch(100), cycle_length=8)

#Pretend I actually had some data files
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.to_dict('list'), target.values))

dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000, seed=123456789)
dataset = dataset.batch(20)
#Pretend I did some parsing here
# dataset = dataset.map(parse_record, num_parallel_calls=20) 
dataset = dataset.filter(lambda x, label: x['trestbps']<135)
```

But this produces the error message:

> ValueError: `predicate` return type must be convertible to a scalar boolean tensor. Was `TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.bool, name=None)`.

What should I do to filter the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you apply the `filter` after the `batch`.
Hence, in the `lambda` expression, `x` is a batch with shape `(None,)` (pass `drop_reminder=True` to `batch` to get shape of `(20,)`), and not a sample. To fix it, you have to call `filter` before `batch`.

There is a solution to "filter" after the `batch`, using a `map` instead. However as you can see, this has a side effect of making batches of variables size: you get a batch of 20 in the input and you remove elements not matching a specific criteria (trestbps < 135), not removing the same number of elements from each batch. Moreover this solution is performing very bad...

```py
import timeit

import pandas as pd

import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tfv1
tfv1.enable_v2_behavior()

def s1(ds):
    dataset = ds
    dataset = dataset.filter(lambda x, label: x['trestbps']<135)
    dataset = dataset.batch(20)
    return dataset

def s2(ds):
    dataset = ds
    dataset = dataset.batch(20)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, label: (tf.nest.map_structure(lambda y: y[x['trestbps'] < 135], x), label[x['trestbps'] < 135]))
    return dataset


def base_ds():
    csv_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('heart.csv', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/applied-dl/heart.csv')

    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    target = df.pop('target')
    df['thal'] = pd.Categorical(df['thal'])
    df['thal'] = df.thal.cat.codes

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.to_dict('list'), target.values))


def main():
    ds = base_ds()
    ds1 = s1(ds)
    ds2 = s2(ds)
    tf.print("DS_S1:", [tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.shape, x) for x in ds1])
    tf.print("DS_S2:", [tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.shape, x) for x in ds2])
    tf.print("Are equals?", [x for x in ds1] == [x for x in ds2])
    tf.print("Contains same elements?", [x for x in ds1.unbatch()] == [x for x in ds2.unbatch()])

    tf.print("Filter and batch:", timeit.timeit(lambda: s1(ds), number=100))
    tf.print("Batch and map:", timeit.timeit(lambda: s2(ds), number=100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Results in:

```
# Tensor shapes
[...]
Are equals? False
Contains same elements? True
Filter and batch: 0.5571189750007761
Batch and map: 15.582061060000342
```

Kind

Comment: I thought `s2` was very clever. Any idea on how to make it work if one of the columns in the dataset is a `SparseTensor`? It gets indexing errors...

Comment: @eggie5 If you carefully read my response, `s2` is NOT the best choice, it is far much slower! I rarely used sparse tensor, but I'm not surprised that `map_structure` is not handling them. You probably have to convert it to a dense vector first.